# Event object in Javascript, trouble finding information

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, cross-browser

I believe there is an object in javascript called `event`, I see it in some code that wasn't written by me in lines that look something like this:

```
event.x + document.body.scrollLeft;
```

I am having trouble finding more out information, furthermore, the object comes up undefined in Firefox. It works fine in all the other browsers. Can anyone provide me with more information? Specifically how do I access this object in Firefox?

Comment: `window.event` is an object in IE with information about the most recent event. Other browsers provide an event object as the first argument to each event callback, e.g., `element.addEventListener("click", function(event) { /* use event in here */ })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Official W3c reccomendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents-h3)

`clientX` and `clientY` are the official event property handlers you are looking for. Although you might want to consider `screenX` and `screenY` too.

---

[**Events (API)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events)

[Creating, triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

[Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Event_handlers)

[Orientation and motion data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained)

---

[**Window Event X and Y property**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Event/EventyandxProperty.htm)

### Explanation

`event.x` and `event.y`, what are those?

**First of all,** the `x` and `y` properties are **not** in all events. It is relative on the event triggered.

Here is an example:

```
document.body.onclick = function(){console.log(window.event.x)};
```

If you paste and execute that code in your browser's console, it will log you the `x` position of the cursor each time you `click`.

---

Although taking a look at this example:

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(){console.log(window.event.x)};
```

The console will log `undefined` each and everytime you release a key from your keyboard, since the `onkeyup()` event does not hold any values for the `x` and `y` properties.

Answer (score 0):

`event` (or just `e`) is a common first parameter name for event handler functions.

In all modern browsers except IE a function registered as an event handler will be passed an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#DOM_Event_interface) object as its first parameter containing information about the event.

In IE similar information is available in the global `event` object ([`window.event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Because of these browser differences you will often see event handler boilerplate code such as:

```
var clicked = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;  // sets e to window.event if no parameter was passed
};
```